# StreamReader does not read xml from html post

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2008, post, streamreader

I am trying to post an xml document from a html page and read the response from the POST like this:

```
string PostBuffer = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream ).ReadToEnd();
```

The streamreader does not read the xml that is on the html document withing the textarea being submitted in the post.  The post works on a form app we have just not on the post from the html.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post the HTML code of the page you are using to post the XML?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the textarea is indeed submitted. use firebug or any other developer tools to see the actual post request sent.

If it is indeed not sent, perhaps the textarea element is outside the `<form></form>` bounds.